# Sublime text 2 : select all text within html tags

Tags: html, sublimetext2

How can i select all the contents within matching html tags in sublime text 2. I've tried "expand selection to brackets" but it doesn't work. For ex.

```
<div class="container">
  <p>
    Text goes here...
  </p>
  <p>
    Text goes here...
  </p>
  <p>
    Text goes here...
  </p>
  more content...
</div>
```

I want to select all the content of div.container

I've found a trick though

What i've tried is just do "cold folding" then just select all of it.
but i hope there's a shortcut or build for it.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Get [Emmet](http://emmet.io/), *“the essential toolkit for web-developers”*, it can [match tag pairs](http://docs.emmet.io/actions/match-pair/) like that.

Then place the cursor anywhere inside of the div, and keep pressing <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>,</kbd> to expand the selection, until the div’s content is selected.

Comment: Thanks. I have already installed emmet
but i didn't know there's a shortcut for this.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: @poke nailed the Emmet command, but `CTRL + ,` did nothing for me on a Mac, and `CMD + ,` just opened settings, but [the comment](http://docs.emmet.io/actions/match-pair/#comment-897785425) suggesting `CTRL + d` worked swimmingly. Thanks for pointing us in the right direction!

Comment: If you hit  `Ctrl` + `Shift` + `A` once while your cursor is in the text, it will select all the text. Hit `Ctrl` + `Shift` + `A` again, and it will select the tags. Keep hitting it, and the selection will keep expanding outwards.

Answer (score 5):

I'm using Sublime Text 2 with Emmet on a Mac and cmd + d is selecting matching words for me, not text between HTML tags.

I was able to achieve what I was looking for (selecting text between opening and closing tags e.g. `<h3>Only Want to Select This Text</h3>`) with cmd + shift + a

Comment: The Windows vs Mac commands are a pain here, try `CTRL + d` instead of `CMD + d` on a Mac.

Answer (score 4):

this works for me

Preferences-> Key Binding-User

then add this into the [ ]

{ "keys": ["ctrl+shift+a"], "command": "expand_selection", "args": {"to": "tag"} },